# Counting the number in series

Tags: r, series

Suppose i have vector z

```
z<-c(6,7,10,11,12,13,17,20,31,32,33,40,56,57,58,59)
```

I want some output that will store the value whenever there is consecutive series as the count of series otherwise simple count of that number if there is no series

```
 [1]  2 4 1 1 3 1 4
```

Here

2 for 6,7

4 for 10,11,12,13

1 for 17

1 for 20

3 for 31,32,33

1 for 40

4 for 56,57,58,59

Hope you understand the question. I have seen example on stackoverflow where one can count total no of similar digit occur like no. of 1's and 2's in the question but didn't find anything similar to this. Please provide the solution

Akrun and bgoltst provides an accurate answer to my post. 
Now I want to solve it without pre-build function using loops . Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rle(c(0,cumsum(diff(z)!=1)))$lengths;
## [1] 2 4 1 1 3 1 4
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark);

bgoldst <- function(z) rle(c(0,cumsum(diff(z)!=1)))$lengths;
akrun1 <- function(z) unname(tapply(z,cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(z)!=1)),length));
akrun2 <- function(z) unname(lengths(split(z, cumsum(c(0,diff(z)!=1)))));
akrun3 <- function(z) tabulate(cumsum(c(TRUE,z[-1L]-z[-length(z)]!=1)));
loop <- function(z) { res <- integer(); if (length(z)==0L) return(res); ri <- 1L; res[ri] <- 1L; for (zi in seq(2L,len=length(z)-1L)) if (z[zi]==z[zi-1L]+1L) res[ri] <- res[ri]+1L else { ri <- ri+1L; res[ri] <- 1L; }; res; };

expected <- c(2L,4L,1L,1L,3L,1L,4L);
identical(expected,bgoldst(z));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,structure(akrun1(z),dim=NULL));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,akrun2(z));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,akrun3(z));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,loop(z));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(z),akrun1(z),akrun2(z),akrun3(z),loop(z));
## Unit: microseconds
##        expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
##  bgoldst(z)  29.081  35.9240  41.52996  40.2000  43.6215 112.901   100
##   akrun1(z) 139.416 152.2450 163.97971 161.6535 169.7790 301.068   100
##   akrun2(z)  94.940 103.0640 110.23655 107.7685 116.3220 168.924   100
##   akrun3(z)   4.277   6.4150   7.37772   7.6980   8.1260  18.817   100
##     loop(z)  42.338  50.4635  58.54198  54.7400  64.3625 136.422   100
```

---

**Scale test:**

```
set.seed(1L);
N <- 1e5L; z <- sort(sample(seq(1L,N*3L),N));
expected <- bgoldst(z);
identical(expected,structure(akrun1(z),dim=NULL));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,akrun2(z));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,akrun3(z));
## [1] TRUE
identical(expected,loop(z));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst(z),akrun1(z),akrun2(z),akrun3(z),loop(z),times=10L);
## Unit: milliseconds
##        expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
##  bgoldst(z)    7.260254    8.391395   11.045106    9.945911   11.704845   17.99818    10
##   akrun1(z)  193.259087  198.464899  215.520530  203.924951  220.394912  300.59812    10
##   akrun2(z)  217.264925  228.902627  263.216340  250.776189  285.028577  400.09614    10
##   akrun3(z)    2.322153    3.299338    6.076256    3.928843    7.569875   18.12305    10
##     loop(z) 2392.752491 2463.121401 2545.236552 2494.690056 2527.570319 2882.29511    10
```

Comment: @bgolst you rock man. If you know how to solve it using loops please tell me. I know they are computationally bad in r

Comment: @learner See edit. I added a loop implementation to the benchmarking.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 unname(tapply(z, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(z)!=1)), FUN= length))
 #[1] 2 4 1 1 3 1 4
```

Or a compact version would be

```
lengths(split(z, cumsum(c(0,diff(z)!=1))))
```

Or we can do

```
tabulate(cumsum(c(TRUE,z[-1]-z[-length(z)] !=1)))
```

Comment: please tell me if you know how to solve it with using loops. I know loops using them bad in R.

Comment: @akrun I updated my benchmarks to include your new solution, it's definitely the fastest. Well done, nice use of `tabulate()`.